# Makefile -std=c99 error

Tags: c, gcc, for-loop, makefile

```
all: matrices.c calculations.o
    gcc -std=c99 matrices.c calculations.o -o -lm PROGRAM2_EXE

lib: matrices.h calculations.c  
    gcc -c -std=c99 calculations.c -o calculations.o

clean: 
    rm matrices.o calculations.o PROGRAM2_EXE
```

This is my makefile for my project. Inside my matrices and my calculations.c there are multiple for loops. The error it gives me is error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in c99 mode but i have my -std=c99 in my file. My questions is

1. How do i fix my makefile to run with the for loops?

Comment: You have no rule for `calculations.o`...

Comment: what do you mean no rule?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction - you don't have one for `calculations.o`.

Comment: its my library (lib: ) using matrices.h and calculations.c together to create calculations.o

Comment: Just add `CFLAGS := -std=c99` at the top of your makefile.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a rule for `calculations.o`. That means that the makefile does not specify how to generate `calculations.o`. You only have a rule for generating `all` and `lib`.

Gmake has some default rules. [One of them](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) is that if you do not have a rule for `filename.o` then it is compiled using `$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c filename.c`.

Your `make all` line is:

```
all: matrices.c calculations.o
```

When you issue `make` or `make all`, gmake checks the dependencies first. `matrices.c` already exists so that's fine. But if `calculations.o` does not exist, then it decides it needs to build `calculations.o`. You didn't specify a rule for `calculations.o`, so the implicit rule is used, which doesn't have `-std=c99` in it.

Note that your `lib` rule is badly written. All rules should either create a file of the corresponding name, or be declared as `.PHONY`.  It seems as if you think that make should somehow deduce that it needs to do `make lib` if the `calculations.o` file does not exist, but that isn't how make works.

To fix your problem , just change `lib:` to `calculations.o:`.  Also, it would be good style to fix the `all` line. The rule does not make `all`, it makes `PROGRAM2_EXE`, so:

```
.PHONY: all
all: PROGRAM2_EXE

PROGRAM2_EXE: matrices.c calculations.o
    gcc -std=c99 matrices.c calculations.o -o PROGRAM2_EXE -lm
```

(Edit: as Chris Dodd points out, the `-o` switch must be immediately followed by the filename)

It would be better style to have a rule `matrices.o` that compiles `matrices.c`, and then a rule `PROGRAM2_EXE: matrices.o calculations.o` that links the two.

Answer (score 2):

This action:

```
gcc -std=c99 matrices.c calculations.o -o -lm PROGRAM2_EXE
```

is telling gcc to produce an executable called `-lm`, which is probably not what you want.

Since you have no rule to produce `connections.o`, make will use its default rule to build it from `connections.c`, which is likely something like (from gmake):

```
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c -o $@ $<
```

Since you don't set `-std=c99` in `CFGLAGS` or `CPPFLAGS`, it won't be used.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following CFLAGS:

> CFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c99

It works very good for me.